# Meteor collection using underscore pluck on an array object

Tags: meteor, underscore.js

Is it possible to use underscore pluck on an array object not just an property name

This works fine as it's property name and just a string ID value.

```
return Collaborators.find({collaboratorId: {$in: _.pluck(topics, '_id')}});
```

But what if I need to use an array like so

```
Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: _.pluck(topics, 'collaboratorsIds')}});
```

Were collaboratorsIds is

```
 [ 'btcTd637xvDrgTieJ', 'DLqCAnw7CSakRTy6S', 'btcTd637xvDrgTieJ' ]
```

Comment: Is `collaboratorsIds` already the array `[ 'btcTd637xvDrgTieJ', 'DLqCAnw7CSakRTy6S', 'btcTd637xvDrgTieJ' ]`? Then can't you just do `Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: collaboratorsIds}});`?

Comment: Yes it's an array but under topics

Comment: What does `topics` look like?

Comment: Sorry it don't post

Yes it's an array but under topics. I'm first doing this to get collaboratorsIds var topics = Topics.find({$or:[{userId: this.userId},{collaboratorsIds: this.userId},{inviteeId:this.userId}]}).fetch();

Comment: So each topic has a list of collaborators, and you want the union of all the topics' collaborators?

Comment: This is the topics array 

[ { title: 'Startup Accelerators', emailSlug: 'accelerators',shortDescription: 'Accelerator programs we should consider.', userId: 'WqRY4rLECkgty3y6q',collaboratorsCount: 1,author: 'Almog Koren',collaboratorsIds: [],submitted: 1413444757366,linksCount: 14,commentsCount: 3,permalinkUser: 'Almog',permalink: 'startup-accelerators',public: false,subscribers: [],subscriberCount: 0, _id: 'Sgy6Hq475rAeQ5dCR' }]

Comment: Each topic has collaboratorsIds array and I would like to find all users that match their ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an array of topics like

```js
var topics = [
  {
    _id: "...",
    title: "...",
    collaboratorsIds: ["qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvbn"],
    ...
  },
  {
    _id: "...",
    title: "...",
    collaboratorsIds: ["yuiop", "hjkl;"],
    ...
  },
  {
    _id: "...",
    title: "...",
    collaboratorsIds: ["qazwsx"],
    ...
  }
]
```

Calling `_.pluck(topics, "collaboratorsIds")` will give you an array of arrays like this:

```js
[["qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvbn"], ["yuiop", "hjkl;"], ["qazwsx"]]
```

You can use `_.flatten(..., true)` to flatten this out into a simple array:

```js
_.flatten(_.pluck(topics, "collaboratorsIds"), true)
  -> ["qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvbn", "yuiop", "hjkl;", "qazwsx"]
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, but my approach was really wrong buy doing it this way I'm getting all the users for each topic and specif users for that topic need to find another way.